# How to change the root view controller of a uinavigation controller embedded in a uitabbarcontroller?

Tags: swift3, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, rootviewcontroller

[image]

Please see the attached image. Here I am having a uitabbarcontroller attached with navigation controller which is having a root view as the "first view". When I click on a button in the first view it goes to the "Second View".

At some point, I want to change the root view controller of navigation controller to Second View and when clicking on a back button in Second View it moves to the first view with tab bar controller.

So for this what should I do? Indirectly I want to say that when the user enters the application he should see the second view controller with navigation and tab bar controller and when he presses back he should move to the first view with navigation controller and tab bar controller

Answer (score 0):

You should swap the whole `UINavigationController` for a new one with the desired root controller as it is not the best practice to replace the root controller of the `UINavigationController` (but it is possible by changing the viewControllers array)

Comment: @peterLapiscu can you please kindly provide some piece of code to swap the viewcontrollers array?

Comment: you just set the property viewControllers to a new array with the root controler being the first object in this array